# Rails one-to-many relation , result is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relation, rabl

I have a simple database that has the following relation

Each Question has one Questiontype (**3 different typs** , such as Questiontype1 , Questiontype2 , Questiontype3 )

in Questiontype has question_id

- **Question.rb** (Model)

> class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
>         belongs_to :questiontype1 
>         belongs_to :questiontype2 
>         belongs_to :questiontype3
>       end

- **Questiontype1.rb** (Model)

> class Questiontype1 < ActiveRecord::Base   has_many :questions ,
>   :foreign_key => "question_id" end

- **show.json.rabl** (I used Rabl)

> object @question attributes :id  child :questiontype1 =>
>   :questiontype1 do   attributes :id end

However, when I get child from Questiontype1 , **result is null**

Can I solve this problem?

Sorry for my English , Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a question is an attribute of the question, not the other way around.  So the `Question` should `has_one :questiontype` and the `Questiontype` should `belongs_to :question`.